# AVAudioPlayer play from buffer

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, download, avaudioplayer

I want to stream audio file from google drive, the only method from google drive sdk from which I can track what is downloaded is `[fetcher setReceivedDataBlock:^(NSData *dataReceivedSoFar)`, so I implemented something like this, but I am not so sure if this is a good solution so I am asking an advice from you guys.

Ok, since I can only get `dataReceivedSoFar`, I am deleting the already downloaded data from it, and then appending the new data to saved data, and start playing with `AVAudioPlayer` when the data length is greater than 100 000 bytes.

Please tell me if this is a good solution and if you have some advice regarding it.

Code:

```
GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher =
        [[self driveService].fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:song.filePath];

    NSArray *myPathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *cachesDir    = [myPathList  objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *songPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [cachesDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Song.%@", [song.name pathExtension]]]];

    [fetcher setReceivedDataBlock:^(NSData *dataReceivedSoFar) {

        NSFileManager *filemgr;
        filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        if (![filemgr fileExistsAtPath: songPath ] == YES)
            [filemgr createFileAtPath:songPath contents:nil attributes:nil];

        NSData *currentData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:songPath];
        NSLog(@"LENGTH: %d", currentData.length);

        NSMutableData *mutableData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:dataReceivedSoFar];

        if (currentData.length > 0) {
            [mutableData replaceBytesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [currentData length]) withBytes:NULL length:0];
        }


        NSFileHandle *handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:songPath];
        [handle seekToEndOfFile];
        [handle writeData:mutableData];
        //[handle synchronizeFile];
        [handle closeFile];

        if (!self.audioPlayer.playing && dataReceivedSoFar.length > 100000)
        {
            NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:songPath];

            self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL error:nil];
            [self.audioPlayer play];
            NSLog(@"Audio player started playing");
        }
```

Comment: With ur Code are u performing Download and Streaming both. Could u reply plz

Comment: Thanks Buddy with ur code i m able to play Audio. Can we Play Video too

Comment: one more thing bro.. it is right way to play from Google Drive...Can u plz tell me

Comment: With same method could u play Video File. Are u using AVPlayer.Let me know.. I will be very thankful to u..

Comment: u can play video also...plz let me know

Comment: Hi, can u tell me how u r playing video from google drive...